# Apache mod-rewrite redirect domain name using querystring

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

We have a client who has many branches around the UK. Some of their branches have their own sites with their own domain names. The client has a part built system where visiting:

```
www.client.com/aboutus.php?id=branchId
```

shows the About Us page for that particular branch. What I need is a way to map specific domains to their branchId (this is all stored in a DB at the moment) so that

```
www.client.com/aboutus.php?id=4
```

maps to

```
www.branchid4.com/aboutus.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Not sure if your domains can work with a single general ruleset (ie. grab the ID and then use it in the rewriterule), otherwise you'll need to repeat the last 3 lines per URL

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?client.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /aboutus\.php\?id=4\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.branchid4.com/about.php? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Sarah. Not sure if that's going to be maintainable as we could have 8 pages per site and over 100 branches. I'm also wondering if I actually stated the redirect properly. I want the user to enter:

    www.branchid4.com/about us

but the page to actually be

    www.client.com/aboutus.php?id=4

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could take the crucial part out of the host name and pass it to your script:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)branchName=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.com$
RewriteRule .* $0?branchName=%1 [L,QSA]
```